# Jsoup to get the price on this website

Tags: jsoup, web-crawler

I wanna get the price **13.490.000** from this [page source](http://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/sony-xperia-z1).

I tried this code but it did't print out anything.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/sony-xperia-z1").get();

Elements spans = doc.select("span[itemprop]");

for (Element span : spans) {
      System.out.println(span.text());
    }
```

Hope somebody can help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the output of `System.out.println(doc.html());` and price is specified in the element with class `contentInfoPriceOrder`, so you can print it like this:

```
Elements spans = doc.select(".contentInfoPriceOrder");
for (Element span : spans) {
    System.out.println(span.child(0).text());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!!, btw, i'm newbie, could you suggest me some tutorials online to learn using Jsoup :D?

Comment: I've never read anything special about Jsoup, just used it a few times.

Comment: If you haven't looked at it yet, I would suggest http://jsoup.org/cookbook/ as a good resource. It gives a basic overview of jsoup and its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one problem that you have is that you are trying to select all of the `<span>` elements with the attribute `itemprop`. Try selecting only the `<span>` element with the attribute `itemprop` with the value equal to `"price"`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/sony-xperia-z1").get();
Element span = doc.select("span[itemprop=\"price\"]").first();
System.out.println(span.text());
```

I put in the `.first()` because I think that jsoup may need you to state that you are selecting one element only. You may not need this, though.